Replicate AI model and version for generating a video from several images and an audio
I've been building a project and I need to generate a video from several images and an audio with replicate AI.
But I don't know what model and version I need.
I hope your great help.
It would be more helpful if you answer with code.
tried to execute a model that generates a video from only one image. but didn't work.
generating video from several images and an audio.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
